# VMWare/VHD image for latest build of SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I want to try out SP 2016. Does Microsoft provide any Virtual Machine image that has everything configured? I searched a bit but didn't find anything other than Azure VM options. I would prefer to run the VM on my local server.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you install the 180 day trial version on your machine ?

Comment: I was just hoping to avoid creating a VM and then install and post config stuff...anyway...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a ready built VM.  You could deploy the Azure VM and then download the VHD to use locally.